# Most mature library for interacting with Twitter using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, twitter

I've tried using Linq to Twitter and it's just a mess. The NuGet package seems to be really outdated, the documentation shows code that doesn't even compile.

I've discovered this [very recent page](http://geekswithblogs.net/WinAZ/archive/2012/01/09/breaking-changes-in-the-linq-to-twitter-search-api.aspx) that says there have been a number of breaking changes, however the code, copy pasted verbatim, doesn't compile.

What .NET lib do you recommend?

- I need to search by hashtags using dates for intervals.

That's pretty much my only requirement. *Possibly* in the future I'll need to be able to post status updates, but that's a YAGNI concern at this point.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using Twitterizer and have been quite happy with it. I just checked the documentation and the `TwitterSearch` (or async version) class should meet your requirements.

http://twitterizer.net

Answer (score 0):

Tweetsharp is the one I've played with.  It's been around for a while and though it isn't actively supported according to the author, it's fairly stable.

https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp

Answer (score 0):

Get the more updated version of Linq-to-twitter from [here](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/).

So, about your question, Linq-to-Twitter is the most complete API for C# I know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using (and developing!) Flurr. http://flurr.codeplex.com/